# Is there a reasonably simple way to automatically generate unique tags for definitions, propositions, lemmas, etc.?

Tags: indexing, overleaf, tags

Particularly, I would like to know if there is a way a novice like me can have *unique* and *unchanging* tags in a manner similar to the tag system of [The Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/) *automatically* assigned to my lemmas and theorems, etc. ? I have had a look at [Gerby](https://gerby-project.github.io/), but frankly, I did not understand much of it. Also, I should note that **I write using Overleaf**.

If you're confused, [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags#:%7E:text=The%20tag%20system%20provides%20stable,to%20the%20same%20mathematical%20result.) is what I mean by "a tag system".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The numbering system is working well for me, but the problem is the document which I'm working on is large, which makes it hard for me to refer people to theorems and lemmas etc. therein, because the numbers keep changing. A system of unique tags that would never change should help with that issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do exactly that. Sorry if I confused you. I'm not too well-versed in LaTeX lingo :p

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added a link which explains what I'm trying to say better than I can. Please have a look.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Let's say that I'm writing down a theorem and I'm labelling it with `\label{theorem1}`, which I can then use `\ref` to refer to, and let's say that this theorem 1.1 is in section 1. But if I were to add a section  which would preceed my original section 1 (making it section 2), my theorem would change to theorem 2.1.

Comment: Keep a counter and generate names programmatically? I’ve posted some code here to do that before.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, but if you want to do it automatically? Maybe you could do something like `\csname\hashlsbel{Fermats Last Theorem}\endcsname`? Don’t see the advantage over `thm:FermatLast`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's not the problem I'm referring to. I write my documents, so I know my labels well. In fact, my labels tend to look like `\label{def: smooth_ring_maps}`. But the issue I have is that it's hard to refer my friends to specific theorems and whatnot, because I update my documents rather frequently.

Comment: @DatMinhHa This sounds like an XY problem to me. Are you thinking of something like `nameref`, or a link with `hyperref` that goes straight to the theorem?

Comment: @Davislor More like a permalink, but yes something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this.  (This example uses LuaLaTeX, but the basic approach works the same in any engine.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bookmarks,
            colorlinks,
            destlabel,
            unicode]{hyperref}

% You would set the PDF title, author, etc. with package options or
% \hypersetup.

\setmathfont{XITS Math}[
  range = \QED,
  Scale = MatchUppercase ]

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\QED}}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{joketheorem}{Russell’s Remark}

\title{A Remark By Russell on Vacuous Truths}
\date{13 March 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This paper recounts a clever extemporaneous \hyperref[rem:vacuous]{illustration}
by Bertrand Russell of the concept of vacuous truth.
\end{abstract}

\clearpage

Once, when Bertrand Russell said in a lecture that any proposition whatsoever
follows logically from a false premise, a student asked him, ``If \(1 + 1 = 1\),
does that prove I'm the Pope?"  Russell replied:

\phantomsection % Add an automatically-named link target.
\begin{joketheorem}
\label{rem:vacuous}
If \(1 + 1 = 1\), I am the pope.

\begin{proof}
I am  one.

The Pope is one.

One and one are one.

Therefore, I and the Pope are one.
\end{proof}
\end{joketheorem}

\end{document}
```

The abstract links to the theorem in the body of the document, with the relative URL `#rem:vacuous`.  A `\ref` or `\autoref` would also work for a numbered theorem.  You can give out an URL like `https://some.edu/~someone/papers/russell.pdf#rem:vacuous` as well.  The `destlabel` option causes each link destination to be named automatically after the following label.

If you want a perma-link to an official version of the document, you can set the `baseurl` as a package option or with `\hypersetup`.

Comment: I don't think this is doing what I would like to make happen. Perhaps this blog post might help clarify my point ? https://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=287

Comment: @DatMinhHa The equivalent to `\cite[Lemma 03PT]{stacks-project}` here is “Retrieved from `https://somewhere.edu/~someone/projects/stacks.pdf#lemma:3pt` on Pi Day 2021,” or just a hyperlink from the name of the lemma to that destination.

Comment: @DatMinhHa That said, you can give arbitrary hyperlink targets to arbitrary URLs with `\hyperlink`, so maybe you define `\StacksProjectURL` somewhere.

Comment: @DatMinhHa I honestly am not clear enough what you’re looking for to write another answer, but I hope this one will be useful to someone else who sees this question in a search.